# "GetCurrentProcessId()" VBA 7 migration

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently migrating a large Excel tool from VBA 6 and Excel 32bit to VBA 7 with Excel 64bit.

The kernel32 function "GetCurrentProcessID" is causing excel to crash. I can recreate the error in an empty excel file with the single line of VBA code

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

If I then call the function within Excel, the number gets populated on the sheet, but Excel crashes after a few seconds. I tried to declare the function with

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As LongPtr
```

and other variations, but nothing seems to work. I am running Microsoft Office 365 with 64 bit.

Did anyone come across this problem before?

Edit: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The presence of the declaration does not cause Excel to crash. Instead, calling it from the spreadsheet causes the crash. I did notice though that calling it from within VBA does not cause a crash, and a wrapper function can be built such that it can be used again from within the spreadsheet. Very strange, but workable solution.

Comment: The original declaration was correct. Even if it weren't, its mere presence should not cause the app to crash!

Comment: According to the documentation it is a 32-bit function that returns a DWORD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid so Rory is correct. You don't need the `LongPtr`.

I have tested the first declaration and it does not crash Excel by itself. You're going to need to show us more of the code to find the problem. Specifically, we need to see a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your first declaration works fine without crashing Excel.

In my testing I noticed that `GetCurrentProcessId` in Excel VBA returns null. So I think that the reason your program is crashing is that you are failing to handle the null. It's not this command but whatever you are doing with the response that is causing the crash. Don't pass null in to native code. It will crash.